# module object has no attribute 'discover_devices'

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying to get Pybluez to work for me.

Here is what happens when I try to discover bluetooth devises.

```
import bluetooth
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>",line1,in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'discover_devices'
```

I'm on windows 8.1, python 2.7.10, pybluez 0.21

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem, I did the mistake of naming my program file `bluetooth.py` , which confused python for the package resolution, you should look out for this silly mistake if this is the case .

If this is not the case then try to put your file in the directory where your bluetooth directory (in my case, `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`) is located and then run it from there, it worked for me.