# BluePy AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'btle'

Tags: python, bluez, texas-instruments, pybluez

I'm trying to run python source code to connect and get data from TI Sensortag CC2650.

`sudo python sensortagcollector.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sensortagcollector.py",
line 223, in <module>
    class ScanDelegate(bluepy.btle.DefaultDelegate):

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'btle'**

    class ScanDelegate(bluepy.btle.DefaultDelegate):
```

Please help to solve the problem.

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04
sensortagcollector.py in home directory
bluepy in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (1.3.0)

Comment: Please see if these answers help:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503884/pybluez-module-object-has-no-attribute-discover-devices and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/bluetooth-module-attribute-error